# C# GUI with Matlab Code

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a C# front end for a bunch of Matlab code.  The majority of the Matlab code has already been written and deals with crunching huge matrices, so I'd prefer if there were some way to just reference the Matlab code rather than compiling it to a library file every time (although I'm not even sure if that's possible).  I'm not extremely familiar with C#, but I'm trying to create a GUI that will take input, call Matlab functions with that input, and then plot the results within the GUI.  I've been having trouble getting the deploytool to work, and I tried getting Matlab set up as a COM port in Visual Studios, so if there are any suggestions about how to make those work for what I want them to do (or completely new suggestions that would work), that would be fantastic.

Comment: Do you have the [MATLAB Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/netbuilder/) toolbox installed?

Comment: I think so - it's through a school license, and my school has most of the toolboxes included.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to start directly .net functions from matlab

you can load assemblies within matlab, and then open the dialog forms.

the complete documentation of the features you can find here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/using-net-libraries-in-matlab.html

I hope you have the latest matlab version, because especially in the 2012 release they included a lot of more conversion functions / .net support in matlab

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll look into it!

Comment: Additional useful link might be http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/use-net-events-in-matlab.html